# не получается убрать автоподгрузку ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

делаю чат для сайта, все работает но выводятся все сообщения из базы каждые две секунды как и указано, однако должны выводиться только если есть новые сообщения. не знаю как исправить.
html:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form_chat">
  <!-- ????????? ?????????? ???? -->
  <div class="modal-header modal-window-chat-header">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <img class="img-circle chat-avatar" src="<?=SITE.$data['user_data']['img_src']?>" /> Chat with <?=$data['author_news']?>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>x</button>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- ???????? ?????????? ?????????? ???? -->
  <div class="modal-body modal-window-chat-body">
    <div class="col-sm-12 window_messages"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group input-group">
        <!--Номер последнего сообщения-->
        <input id="last_act" name="last_act" type="hidden" value="0" />

        <!--Блокировка повторного выполнения функции get_chat_messages()-->
        <input id="block" name="block" type="hidden" value="no" />
        <input type="hidden" class="id_user_to" name="id_user_to" value="<?=$data['user_data']['id']?>" />
        <input type="hidden" class="id_user_from" name="id_user_from" value="<?=$data['user_auth_id']?>" />
        <textarea class="textarea_chat" name="text_chat"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-default chat-button" type="button" name="send_message" value="Send" />
</div>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// делаем фокус на поле ввода при загрузке страницы
if ($(".textarea_chat").size()>0)
{
    $(".textarea_chat").focus();
}
//Функция отправки сообщения
function send_message()
{
    //Считываем сообщение из поля ввода
    var text_chat = $(".textarea_chat").val();
    var id_user_to = $(".id_user_to").val();
    var id_user_from = $(".id_user_from").val();

    // Отсылаем паметры
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php?route=chat/add_message",
            data:{
                'action':'add_message',
                'id_user_to': id_user_to,
                'id_user_from': id_user_from,
                'textarea_chat': text_chat
            },

            // Выводим то что вернул PHP
            success: function(html)
            {
                //Если все успешно, загружаем сообщения
                load_messages();
                //Очищаем форму ввода сообщения
                $(".textarea_chat").val('');
            }
    });
}

//Функция загрузки сообщений
function load_messages()
{

    //Считываем сообщение из поля ввода
    var id_user_to = $(".id_user_to").val();
    var id_user_from = $(".id_user_from").val();

    // если не выставлена блокировка повторного выполнения данной функции, продолжаем
     if ($('#block').val() == 'no')
     {
         //$('#block').val('yes'); // ставим блокировку

         var last_act = $('#last_act').val();
         //alert (last_act);
         $.ajax(
         {
             url: 'index.php?route=chat/load_messages',
             type: 'POST',
             data:
             {
                 'action': 'get_chat_message',
                 'last_act': last_act,
                 'id_user_to': id_user_to,
                 'id_user_from': id_user_from
             },
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (result)
             {
                 // добавляем в текстовое поле новые сообщения
                 $('.window_messages').append(result.message_code);

                 // автопрокрутка текстового поля вниз
                 $('.window_messages').scrollTop($('.window_messages').scrollTop()+100*$('.chat_post_my, .chat_post_other').size()); 
                 //alert($('#last_act').val()+"   "+result.last_act);
                 if($('#last_act').val() < result.last_act) {
                    $('#block').val('yes');
                    // обновляем значение последнего сообщения
                    $('#last_act').val=(result.last_act);                        
                   else {
                    $('#block').val('no');



                 }
                 //$('#block').val('no');// убираем блокировку
              }
         });
     }
}

// прокрутка текстового поля до последнего сообщения вниз
$('.window_messages').scrollTop($('.window_messages').scrollTop()+100*$('.chat_post_my, .chat_post_other').size());

// отправка сообщений при нажатии кнопки "Ответить"
$('.chat-button').click(function()
{
    send_message();
});

// проверяем наличие новых сообщений каждые 2 секунды
 setIcess: function (
 {
     load_messages();
 }, 2000);

 // отправка сообщений при нажатии клавиши "Enter"
 $('.textarea_chat').keyup(function(event)
 {
     if (event.which == 13)
     {
         send_message();
     }
 });
 });
```

php:

```
public function action_add_message () {

        if ($_POST['action'] == 'add_message') {
            $this->valid->secureData($_POST);

            $addMessage = array (
                'id_user_to' => $_POST['id_user_to'],
                'id_user_from' => $_POST['id_user_from'],
                'message_text' => $_POST['textarea_chat'],
                'date_message' => time()
            );

            $this->model_chat->AddMessages($addMessage);
        }
   }

   public function action_load_messages () {
        if($_POST['action'] == 'get_chat_message') {

            $last_act = $this->valid->secureData($_POST['last_act']);// ����� ������� ���������� ���������

            $messages = $this->model_chat->LoadMessages($_POST['id_user_to'], $_POST['id_user_from']);

            foreach($messages as $key => $val) {
                if ($_SESSION['id_user_from'] == $val['user_from']) {
                    $message_code .= '<p class="chat_post_my"><span class="chat_mess_time"><strong>['.date("H:i:s", $val['date_message']).']</strong> - </span><span class="chat_nickname">'.$val['nickname'].': </span>'.$val['message_text'].'</p>';
                } else {
                    $message_code .= '<p class="chat_post_my"><span class="chat_mess_time"><strong>['.date("H:i:s", $val['date_message']).']</strong> - </span><span class="chat_nickname">'.$val['nickname'].': </span>'.$val['message_text'].'</p>';
                }
                $last_act = $val['id'];
            }

            $data_str = array('message_code' => $message_code, 'last_act' => $last_act);
            echo json_encode($data_str);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я как понял, для проверки используете `$last_act`, тогда у вас в php при работе с моделью (`$this->model_chat->LoadMessages`) нигде не используется данная переменная, вы просто делаете выгрузку всех сообщений `от` и `кому`, полагаю нужно добавить еще проверку по `$last_act`

Comment: не получается, может подскажете другие примеры реализации?